# Mobiscroll formatting date and time to Dayday:hour:minute

Tags: javascript, mobiscroll

I'm trying to find a way to combine the day/date/month into one string on the first wheel into:

```
  1st         2nd   3rd
+------------+----+----+
| thu 27 sep | 17 | 00 |
| fri 28 sep | 18 | 00 |
+------------+----+----+
```

Where first wheel is: day/Date/month, second: hour, third: minute
Any clues?

A follow up question would be: How do I get todays day to display as 'Today' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by generating your own custom wheels. I have put an example of doing it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rd5m8/1/

You will have to rewrite a bit in the parseValue, and formatResult if you want today displayed as 'Today'. Let me know if you have any difficulties!

Comment: Many many thanks. This does the trick. Thanks for the elaborative code.